# type for $event rather than any?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using angular $event in one of my function as a parameter.
I don't want to use 'any' type for evt in function definition. 
what is the preferable alternative for evt?

Html

```
<button class="edit-button" (click)="invokeEdit($event)">Edit</button>
```

TypeScript

```
public invokeEdit(evt: any): void {
    evt.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/user-input#type-the-event

Comment: ```$event``` is an object which has many properties with their own types, which property do you want from ```$event```?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the mouse event **MouseEvent** interface.
Please check the below link for more information.

[Reference one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click)

[Reference two](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button)

> Html:-

```
<button (click)="invokeEdit($event)" type="submit" mat-raised-button color="default">Edit</button>
```

> TypeScript:-

```
public invokeEdit(event: MouseEvent): void {          
 console.log(event); 
 event.stopPropagation();
}
```